# Why can an "in-place" function not reference the class it is in?

Tags: typescript, protractor, automated-tests

I have this code that I'm using that waits for a breadcrumb on a page to have loaded. The problem is the first line in which I create my own function to use instead of an ExpectedCondition as the ExpectedConditions do not do a contains check and that's what I need in this place.  Since I made my own in-place function, I seem to be outside the realm of the class I'm in.  So I'm lost on why this breaks the scoping and why I can't reference the other method `getProjectNameBreadCrumbText()` that exists in my class from this in place method.

I found the issue when I received the error `Failed: Cannot read property 'getProjectNameBreadCrumbText' of undefined`.  I understand that the `this` is undefined, but I do not understand why.  I also do not know if I could possibly pass the `this` and thus the class I'm in by reference somehow because I'm not sure of the exact terminology of the code I'm currently using.

```
// My Page Object class
export class MapperPage {
    ...
    async getProjectNameBreadCrumbText() {
        return await this.breadCrumbs.get(2).getText();
    }
    ...
    async waitAndVerifyProjectNameBreadCrumbs(projectName: string) {
        await browser.wait(async function() {return (await this.getProjectNameBreadCrumbText()).indexOf(projectName) > -1;},
            this.DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME_SECONDS * 1000, 'Name Breadcrumb for this page never loaded.');
        expect(await this.getProjectNameBreadCrumbText()).toContain(projectName);
        expect(await this.getProjectMapperBreadCrumbText()).toEqual(this.MAPPER_BREADCRUMB);
    }
}


// In my test I call the waitAndVerify method like so
...
it('test', async() => {
    const PROJECT_NAME = 'Project Name';
    ... // do other things
    // wait for the page to load by making sure the breadcrumbs have loaded
    await waitAndVerifyProjectNameBreadCrumbs(this.PROJECT_NAME);
});
```

My apologies if this is a duplicate question, I didn't know how to Google what I'm asking for as I'm not sure of the correct terminologies for this code I'm  writing.

Comment: what are you expecting `this` to be bound to? a class instance? if it is being invoked via a callback you'll have to bind this to it.  can you post a more complete example? i.e. how you are invoking this and the class it is declared in?

Comment: I added further code to clarify how the function was being called.  It lives in a pageObject class and I was expecting this to refer to that class so I could call another function that lived in that same class.  The answer posted was the final solution.  My apologies for any confusion. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are passing a function as a parameter. So [the scope can be changed](https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/#scope-and-this). You can use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in order to have access to a correct scope:

```
await browser.wait(
    async () => (await this.getProjectNameBreadCrumbText()).includes(projectName),
    this.DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME_SECONDS * 1000, 
    'Name Breadcrumb for this page never loaded.'
);
```

As other option - you can [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) a function to a required scope manually:

```
this.getProjectNameBreadCrumbText = this.getProjectNameBreadCrumbText.bind(this);
await browser.wait(
    async function() {return (await this.getProjectNameBreadCrumbText()).indexOf(projectName) > -1;},
    this.DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME_SECONDS * 1000, 
    'Name Breadcrumb for this page never loaded.')
```

Comment: The first one was what I needed! I also understand the binding, but I'd prefer to keep things simple.  I also appreciate the links to further reading so I understand what I'm trying to do. And the subtle hint to use includes, as I didn't know it existed. Thanks again!